# Creating dynamic HoverTool tooltips in Bokeh based off of a dropdown using CustomJS callbacks

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, hover, tooltip, bokeh

I've got a scatterplot I've created in Bokeh, and I'd very much like to be able to change what tooltips display on the Hovertool depending on your selection in a dropdown menu. If "Stat Set 1" is selected, I want to show stats 1&2. If "Stat Set 2" is selected, I want to show stats 3,4,5.

I'd like the end result to be a html file, so using CustomJS for the call back is probably a must. Here is where I have managed to get with the code. The issue is likely with the callback, as I'm not at all sure how to mess with tooltips via a callback.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.layouts import row

#Create a dataframe with x and y coordinates and 4 different statistics
df = pd.DataFrame({
            'x':[1,2,3],
            'y':[1,2,3],
            'stat1':[1,2,3],
            'stat2':[4,5,6],
            'stat3':[7,8,9],
            'stat4':[10,11,12],
            'stat5':[13,14,15]
})

#Create Bokeh's ColumnDataSource
source=ColumnDataSource(data=df)

#Create the different options for the Hovertool tooltips
option1=[('Stat1','@stat1'),
         ('Stat2','@stat2')]

option2=[('Stat3','@stat3'),
         ('Stat4','@stat4'),
         ('Stat5','@stat5')]

#Set the default option for the Hovertool tooltips
hover=HoverTool(tooltips=option1)

#Create the figure
plot = figure(tools=[hover])
plot.circle('x', 'y', source=source)

#Create the callback that will update the tooltips
callback = CustomJS (args=dict(tt=plot.hover), code="""
    if (cb_obj.value='Stat Set 1') {
        tt.tooltips=option1
    } else {
        tt.tooltips=option2
    }
    """)

#Create a dropdown menu that allows you to change which set of stats will populate the tooltips
stat_select=Select(options=['Stat Set 1', 'Stat Set 2'],
                        value='Stat Set 1',
                         title='What stats set do you want to see when you hover?', callback=callback)

show(row(stat_select,plot))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found someone with the [answer over on the Bokeh Discourse](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/updating-hovertools-on-change-with-custom-js/3262/3).

`plot.hover` returns a list, as a plot can have multiple tooltips.
So instead of using `tt.tooltips = option1`, `tt` must be subscripted to use the first entry of the list, ie `tt[0].tooltips = option1`.

```
options = [option1, option2]

#Create the callback that will update the tooltips

callback = CustomJS (args=dict(tt=plot.hover, opts=options), code="""

if (cb_obj.value=='Stat Set 1') {

    tt[0].tooltips=opts[0]

} else {

    tt[0].tooltips=opts[1]

}

""")
```